# How to check if Key inv_ has the value of Deer Quick.db

Tags: javascript, discord.js, quick.db

Hello I am making a discord economy bot and I made a hunt command now I want to know that how to detect if the key inv_ has the value of deer

for hunting I used this code well I added only 1 animal till now
for hunting

```js
if(message.content === `${defaultprefix}hunt`){
  var animalHunt = [1 , 2 , 3 , 4 , 5]
  var animalHunted = animalHunt[Math.floor(Math.random()*animalHunt.length)];
  if(animalHunted === 1){
    db.push(message.author.id + 'inv_', 'Deer')
    message.channel.send("You were hunting and hunted a deer ")
  }
}
```

using djs v12

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`.get()`](https://quickdb.js.org/overview/docs#get) function to return the [Array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) (since you used [`.push()`](https://quickdb.js.org/overview/docs#push), the data on the `<userID>.inv` will be an array), then simply search if there's a specific animal in it, in your case you can use this :

```js
    let userinv = db.get(message.author.id + 'inv_')
    if(userinv.includes('Deer')) return message.channel.send('You do have a Deer  !')
  else return message.channel.send("You don't")
```

And if you want to delete the Deer from the inventory you can use get the array, change it, and set it back.

```js
// We get the array from the database.
let userinv = db.get(message.author.id + 'inv_')
// Remove all the "Deer"
let newuserinv = userinv.filter(animals => animals !== "Deer")
// And we set the array back to the database.
db.set(message.author.id + 'inv_',newuserinv)
```

Comment: Can I have your discord id so that I can msg you if I have some issues

Comment: Now I want to make a sell cmd I done thing now want to now how to db.delete deer

Comment: That dont work.

Comment: @vaijayantipethe Here I changed my answer to support how to delete the Deer, if it fixed your problem just click the check mark since it answered your question and  create a new question for your new problem !

Comment: .includes dont work

Comment: That means that the database don't have the ${userID}_inv, you have to set it yourself like you did in your first code